# Showing a better onscreen keyboard on MacOS

Tags: macos, keyboard, big-sur, accessibility

I am looking for an old style onscreen keyboard. Is this still an option on MacOS, or is there a third party application? Or has it been there all along but I missed it?

It used to look something like this:

[image]

The current Keyboard Viewer (a) doesn’t show the extended keyboard, which I do have, and (b) is pretty ugly; no, it’s *very* ugly.

Among other things, I want to record keyboard activity for teaching purposes.

I am using MacOS Big Sur. I have an Apple bluetooth extended keyboard. I don’t know whether the fact that I’m using the Australian keyboard is relevant.

For clarification - Big Sur Keyboard Viewer vs Mojave Keyboard Viewer [both on Extended UK Keyboards] - the one accessed from the Keyboard/Language menu icon in each case. the Big Sur one now looks like the old Accessibility Viewer.
Image taken by floating the Mojave one over a Remote Desktop Big Sur session.

[image]

Comment: I wasn't aware they'd messed it up quite so much in Big Sur - i use it a lot, but still in Mojave. Added images of old & new for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Which onscreen keyboard are we talking about? If you check `Accessibility` / `keyboard` / `Viewer`, there's a button `Panel Editor...`, and the ellipsis is both strange and somewhat fitting, because it's a whole new world hiding behind it.

The screenshot shows the editor (top), the keyboard in use (bottom), and the Accessibility preferences where it can be accessed.

I dragged a JIS (large) keyboard into service, added a custom `YOUR KEY HERE!` at an unfortunate location, and a *word completion bar* (useful, considering bars usually impair my word finding skills).

There are prefab layouts and panels for most any need, and it allows customisation for individual applications.

It's slightly ugly, yes. I guess that's the fate of Apple keyboards both real and virtual: they get flat and dark. [image]

Comment: "There are prefab layouts and panels for most any need, and it allows customisation for individual applications." Sadly there are no prefab layouts for Apple's extended keyboards. The one I built for myself manages to look worse than the default and have less functionality, e.g. the number pad doesn't flash when I hit the key; also I can see no way to make dual function keys although they do come with the prefab layouts ...